# How to make CLion automatically build on save

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I remember when I program Java in Eclipse, Eclipse can automatically build the project whenever I change a java file.

Is it possible for CLion to automatically build my C++ project as well?

I'm asking this because compilation in my project (depending on ROS) is slow, and I often realize that I should waste less time on this.

Comment: If compilation is slow, then would it not make everything slower if you compile on save instead of on demand?

Comment: @draw Did you finally find a solution that you want to share with us?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to press build instead of save (I have eclipse keyboard shortcuts so I press -B). Build saves the files automatically.

Maybe reassign build to -S

And to answer "Some programmer dude": The build is in the background so you can continue working if you so like.